# React Native: How to store chats client-side?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently building a social networking app with React Native for both, Android and iOS. The app will also allow the users to chat with each other. The chats should be available offline (like WhatsApp Messenger and Facebook Messenger).

What would be some of the ways, or the best way, to store the chats client-side?

Options I'm aware of:

- AsyncStorage (only allows 6MB, not sure if this is good or fast enough)
- Client-side DB *e.g. Realm* (I've been told this might be an overkill)
- mobx-persist (not sure if this would be ideal/recommended)
- redux-persist (same as above)

Comment: Honestly, from a sanity standpoint I wouldn't see a database as overkill. It keeps everything structured, consistent and buttoned up. They are exactly for storing and recalling vast amounts of data, chats included.

Comment: Realm isn't overkill at all and would work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you worried that your app will be too 'heavy'? I can understand storing messages if messaging is not main feature of the app, but with social networking you'll need to store tons of messages on device. Does not look good from user experience. Try chat backend solution like [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/) I used their [ReactNative SDK](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/react-native) and it worked just fine